# Let $\mathcal{V}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^k$. Show $\{\langle u,v\rangle=0\forall v\in\mathcal{V}\implies u =0_k\} \iff$ span$(\mathcal{V})=\mathbb{R}^k$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, normed-spaces

I am trying to show the following but seem to be at a complete loss on how to do it.

Let $\mathcal{V} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^k$. Then show that $\{ \langle u, v\rangle= 0$ for all $v \in \mathcal{V} \implies u = 0_k\} \iff \operatorname{span}(\mathcal{V}) = \mathbb{R}^k$. This is a logical statement of the form $\{a \implies b \}\iff c$. So I am trying to prove the forward direction by saying $\neg c \implies\{  \langle u, v\rangle = 0$ for all $v \in \mathcal{V} \nrightarrow u = 0_k\}$

For this I assume that $\operatorname{span}(\mathcal{V}) \neq \mathbb{R}^k$. So $\mathcal{V}$ does not contain a set of $k$ independent vectors. Then I wanna say that $\operatorname{Ker}(\mathcal{V}) \neq \emptyset$ and that I can take a vector $w$ from $\operatorname{Ker}(\mathcal{V})$ such that $\langle w, v\rangle$. But I am not sure if this is right or not since we usually talk of the kernel with respect to a linear transformation. Can someone show me how to prove this rigorously, and I am also not sure how to go about showing the other direction.

Comment: Use \langle and \rangle, not < and >. The latter are operators, not delimiters, so the spacing is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathcal{V} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^k$ let $\mathcal{U}=\mathcal{V}^{\perp}$ so $\mathbb{R}^k=\mathcal{V}\bigoplus\mathcal{U}$ furthermore we know for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^k: x \perp y \Leftrightarrow$ $<x,y>=0$

$\Leftarrow :$ span$(\mathcal{V})=\mathbb{R}^k \rightarrow $span$(\mathcal{U})={\{0\}}$ so the left side holds.

$\Rightarrow:$ For any $v\in\mathcal{V}$ $u=0$ so $\mathcal{U}={\{0\}} \rightarrow $ span$(\mathcal{V})=\mathbb{R}^k$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ be a basis of $\mathrm{span}(\mathcal{V})$. Let $u \in \mathbb{R}^k \setminus \mathrm{span}(\mathcal{V})$. Then let $$\hat{u} = u - \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{\langle u, v_i\rangle}{\langle v_i, v_i \rangle} v_i.$$ Now $\hat{u} \ne 0$, because that would imply $u \in \mathrm{span}(\mathcal{V})$. Now $\langle \hat{u}, v_i\rangle = 0$ for all $i = 1, \ldots, n$, hence $\langle \hat{u}, v\rangle = 0$ for all $v \in \mathrm{span}(\mathcal{V})$.

Also if $\langle u, v\rangle = 0$ $\forall v \in \mathbb{R}^k \implies u = 0$, since in particular $\langle u, cu\rangle=c\langle u,u\rangle=0\implies u=0$.

Comment: thanks a lot, can you also mention how to prove the other side of the if and only if implication

Comment: The last line is the reverse implication.